# Why I get this exception from AutoclearedValue?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use AutoclearedValue in android, and in my old tablet which runs Android 4.4.4 I always get an exception like this: should never call auto-cleared-value get when it might not be available from AutoclearedValue class

I dont understand why, bacause in newer devices I don't get this exception.

The scenario is the following: I click an item in recyclerview, than an another fragment will open. In this fragment I implemented simple scrollview listener, it works perfectly. When I click back button, to navigate back to the previous fragment, then I get the exception.

My AutoClearedValue class:

```
class AutoClearedValue<T : Any>(val fragment: Fragment) : ReadWriteProperty<Fragment, T> {
    private var _value: T? = null

    init {
        fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(object: DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observe(fragment) { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                    viewLifecycleOwner?.lifecycle?.addObserver(object: DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                        override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                            _value = null
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return _value ?: throw IllegalStateException(
            "should never call auto-cleared-value get when it might not be available"
        )
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        _value = value
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an [AutoClearedValue] associated with this fragment.
 */
fun <T : Any> Fragment.autoCleared() = AutoClearedValue<T>(this)
```

And my listener where the exception comes from:

```
    private fun initListeners() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            binding.freightTaskRowDetailScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, oldScrollY ->
                if (binding.showFab == true) {
                    if (scrollY <= oldScrollY) {
                        if (!binding.expandableFab.isShown)
                            binding.expandableFab.showHide()
                    } else {
                        if (binding.expandableFab.isShown)
                            binding.expandableFab.showHide()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            binding.freightTaskRowDetailScrollView.viewTreeObserver
                .addOnScrollChangedListener {
                    if (binding.showFab == true) { [this line]
                        if (!binding.freightTaskRowDetailScrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                            if (binding.expandableFab.isShown)
                                binding.expandableFab.showHide()
                        }
                        if (!binding.freightTaskRowDetailScrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                            if (!binding.expandableFab.isShown)
                                binding.expandableFab.showHide()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The AutoClearedValue has a bug in terms of ViewBinding, instead you should use the class presented in this link for ViewBinding.

https://itnext.io/an-update-to-the-fragmentviewbindingdelegate-the-bug-weve-inherited-from-autoclearedvalue-7fc0a89fcae1

**OLD ANSWER**

You have the **OLD** version of this class.

Check the new implementation here:

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/7be0ea4d9fb07fa51dbd75b0fc656be86de6fc2a/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/AutoClearedValue.kt